# iOS 5: Can you override UIAppearance customisations in specific classes?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, ios5

I'm building an app with many view controllers: I have a `UITabBarController` which holds 4 `UINavigationController`. I want all the nav bars to be my custom color, say blue, which I achieve by doing this in my app delegate:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

But I also have one special view controller which has a map, and for this view controller I want to override the blue navbar set using `UIAppearance` to make it the black opaque style. I've tried by calling this inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

But nothing happens. Can this be done or do I have to abandon UIAppearance and set the properties on `navigationBar` manually for each view controller?

Answer (score 33):

The way you are doing it is supposed to work, but it doesn't. This does work though:

## Swift 4

```
UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [YourOtherVC.self]).tintColor = .black
```

## Objective-C

```
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[YourOtherVC class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Answer (score 9):

Move your changes to viewWillAppear: instead of viewDidLoad: and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

For that you would do:

```
id specialNavBarAppearance = [UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[SpecialViewController class], nil];

[specialNavBarAppearance setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
[specialNavBarAppearance setTranslucent:YES];
```

Comment: My `SpecialViewController`'s view just get pushed onto the nav controller stack though. I have created the view hierarchy in a Storyboard, so none of my view controllers has a pointer to the navcontroller in question. The way I understand it, the UINavigationBar in question needs to be contained within a container class whose appearance proxy I talk to. Does that mean I have to abandon the Storyboard?

Comment: Calling setTranslucent on an appearance proxy doesn't actually work. It says `Illegal property type, c in invocation selector, _UIAppearance_setTranslucent:'`